# Asp.net web restful API

Tags: c#, api, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm a new in API
I have a c# windows application connected to entity framework now I want to change that I want to connect my app to Asp.net web API (restful) and this service connect with database through entity framework I add my entity framework code to class library and reference it to the service
here my controller code is it correct or need to edit somethings on it? and after this step I need to consume the service in my windows app and then host it right ?

```
public class BuyAndRechargeController : ApiController
{
    public readonly BuyAndRechargeSystemModel _dataBaseEntities = new BuyAndRechargeSystemModel(new DatabaseConfiguration().GetAppConfiguration());
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("phoneNumberChecking")]
    public bool CheckExistingPhoneNumber(string phoneNumberChecking)
    {
        return (_dataBaseEntities.Customers.Count(number => number.PhoneNumber == phoneNumberChecking) != 0);
    }

    [ActionName("GetCustomers")]
    public List<Customer> GetCustomers()
    {
        List<Customer> customerList = new List<Customer>();
        customerList = _dataBaseEntities.Customers.Select(customer => new Customer
        {
            CustomerName = customer.Name,
            CustomerPhoneNumber = customer.PhoneNumber,
            CustomerBirthdate = customer.BirthDate,
            CustomerPackageName = customer.Packages.Name,
            CustomerBalance = (decimal)customer.Balance
        }).ToList();

        return customerList;
    }

    [ActionName("GetCustomerInformation")]
    public Customer GetCustomerInformation(string phoneNumber)
    {
        Customer customerInformation;
        customerInformation = _dataBaseEntities.Customers
            .Where(customer => customer.PhoneNumber.Equals(phoneNumber)).Select(customer => new Customer
            {
                CustomerName = customer.Name,
                CustomerPhoneNumber = customer.PhoneNumber,
                CustomerBirthdate = customer.BirthDate,
                CustomerPackageName = customer.Packages.Name,
                CustomerBalance = (decimal)customer.Balance
            }).Single();

        return customerInformation;
    }

    [HttpPut]
    [ActionName("RechargeBalance")]
    public string RechargeBalance(string phoneNumber, string amount)
    {//FirstOrDefault --> single
        Customers customer = _dataBaseEntities.Customers.Single(customerPhoneNumber =>
            customerPhoneNumber.PhoneNumber.Equals(phoneNumber));
        customer.Balance = customer.Balance + Convert.ToDecimal(amount);
        IFormatProvider culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        customer.ExpireDate = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"), "dd-MM-yyyy", culture);
        _dataBaseEntities.SaveChanges();
        return customer.Balance.ToString();
    }
    [ActionName("GetPackagesList")]
    public List<string> GetPackagesList(string packageType)
    {
        List<string> packagesList = _dataBaseEntities.Packages.Where(package => package.Type.Equals(packageType))
            .Select(package => package.Name).ToList();
        return packagesList;
    }

    [ActionName("GetFilteredCustomers")]
    public List<Customer> GetFilteredCustomers(string search)
    {
        List<Customer> customerList = new List<Customer>();
        customerList =
            _dataBaseEntities.Customers.Where(customer => customer.Name.Contains(search) || customer.PhoneNumber.Contains(search)).Select(customer => new Customer
            {
                CustomerName = customer.Name,
                CustomerPhoneNumber = customer.PhoneNumber,
                CustomerBirthdate = customer.BirthDate,
                CustomerPackageName = customer.Packages.Name,
                CustomerBalance = Convert.ToDecimal(customer.Balance)
            }).ToList();
        return customerList;
    }

    [ActionName("DeleteCustomers")]
    public bool DeleteCustomers(string[] customerPhoneNumber)
    {
        bool isDeleted = true;
        bool result = false;
        List<Customers> deleteQuery = new List<Customers>();
        foreach (string phoneNumber in customerPhoneNumber)
        {
            Customers customerRow = _dataBaseEntities.Customers.Single(customer => customer.PhoneNumber.Equals(phoneNumber));
            deleteQuery.Add(customerRow);

            if (customerRow != null)
            {
                isDeleted = true && isDeleted;
            }
            else
            {
                isDeleted = false && isDeleted;
                break;
            }
        }

        foreach (Customers delete in deleteQuery)
        {

            if (isDeleted)
            {
                _dataBaseEntities.Customers.Remove(delete);
                _dataBaseEntities.SaveChanges();
                result = true;
            }
            else
            {
                result = false;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("AddPackage")]
    public bool AddPackage(string packageType, string packageName, string packagePrice)
    {
        bool isAdded = false;
        try
        {
            Packages package = new Packages();
            package.Name = packageName;
            package.Type = packageType;
            package.price = Int32.Parse(packagePrice);
            _dataBaseEntities.Packages.Add(package);
            _dataBaseEntities.SaveChanges();
            isAdded = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            isAdded = false;
        }

        return isAdded;
    }

    [HttpGet]   
    [ActionName("CheckIfNoCustomers")]
    public bool CheckIfNoCustomers()
    {
        bool isNoCustomer = false;
        int countOfCustomers = _dataBaseEntities.Customers.Count();
        if (countOfCustomers == 0)
        {
            isNoCustomer = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isNoCustomer = false;
        }
        return isNoCustomer;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("AddCustomer")]
    public bool AddCustomer(string packageName, string phoneNumber, string customerName, string customerBirthDate)
    {
        bool result = false;
        try
        {
            Customers customer = new Customers();
            int packageId = _dataBaseEntities.Packages.Where(package => package.Name.Equals(packageName))
                .Select(package => package.ID).Single();
            int packagePrice = _dataBaseEntities.Packages.Where(package => package.Name.Equals(packageName))
                .Select(package => package.price).Single();
            string expireDateADateTime = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            DateTime expireDate = DateTime.ParseExact(expireDateADateTime, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            customer.Name = customerName;
            customer.PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
            customer.BirthDate = customerBirthDate;
            customer.PackageID = packageId;
            customer.ExpireDate = expireDate;
            customer.Balance = packagePrice;
            _dataBaseEntities.Customers.Add(customer);
            _dataBaseEntities.SaveChanges();
            result = true;
        }

        catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
        {
            e.EntityValidationErrors.SelectMany(error => error.ValidationErrors).ToList().ForEach(
                item => Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", item.PropertyName, item.ErrorMessage));
            result = false;
            WriteToLogFile.WriteToLogErrorFile(e);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = false;
            WriteToLogFile.WriteToLogErrorFile(ex);
        }

        return result;
    }

    [ActionName("GetPackageTypeFromName")]
    public string GetPackageTypeFromName(string packageName)
    {
        string packageType = _dataBaseEntities.Packages.Where(package => package.Name.Equals(packageName))
            .Select(package => package.Type).Single();
        return packageType;
    }

    [ActionName("GetExpireDate")]
    public DateTime GetExpireDate(string phoneNumber)
    {
        DateTime? expireDate = _dataBaseEntities.Customers
            .Where(customer => customer.PhoneNumber.Equals(phoneNumber)).Select(customer => customer.ExpireDate)
            .Single();
        return (DateTime)expireDate;
    }

    [HttpPut]
    [ActionName("EditCustomer")]
    public bool EditCustomer(string packageName, string editCustomerName, string editCustomerBirthDate, string phoneNumber)
    {
        bool isEdited = false;

        Customers customer =
            _dataBaseEntities.Customers.FirstOrDefault(customerPhone => customerPhone.PhoneNumber.Equals(phoneNumber));
        if (customer != null)
        {
            int packageId = _dataBaseEntities.Packages.Where(package => package.Name.Equals(packageName))
                .Select(package => package.ID).Single();
            customer.Name = editCustomerName;
            customer.BirthDate = editCustomerBirthDate;
            customer.PackageID = packageId;
            _dataBaseEntities.SaveChanges();
            isEdited = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isEdited = false;
        }
        return isEdited;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("CheckExistingPackages")]
    public bool CheckExistingPackages(string packageName)
    {
        bool existPackage = false;
        int packages = _dataBaseEntities.Packages.Where(package => package.Name == packageName)
            .Select(package => packageName).Count();
        if (packages != 0)
        {
            existPackage = true;
        }
        return existPackage;
    }
}
```

Comment: To connect your C# Windows application to an ASP.NET Web API, you can use the HttpClient class to send HTTP requests to the API endpoints

Comment: Yes, you need to host the restful api, and consume it from the HTTP client from the windows app

Comment: which step first host or consume ?

Comment: You need your web api before you can consume it. So I suggest you write a test web api controller. It is usual to define dto which are not entity framework classes purely for transfer purposes. Copy data to one of these and serialise to return it.  Personally, I would suggest considering a lighter weight orm than entity framework as well. By the time you turn all the tracking off etc EF doesn't really offer so much more than a micro orm. I used to like EF but now prefer dapper.  EF migrations might sway the balance but I've used other mechanisms instead for some time now.

Comment: It's more usual to use the dependency injection in web api. The request pipeline will provide registered instances to your parameterised constructor. I suggest you take a look. And you'll likely want some logging such as nlog.  A controller would usually hide errors since they can potentially be used by an attacker. Usual to just return a 500 if anything goes wrong and log what really happened.  It is also usual to make controller endpoints async. Often async Task'<t>' Then use async down to the database. Also usual to minimise the code in a controller and do the "work" in injected classes.